# What is an Intel Core i3?

Tags: intel-core-i3

I know that a Dual Core is generally worse than a Core 2 Duo.

Where does a Core i3 fit into that?

Does it have dual cores?  Is it better or worse or just confusing?

Comment: **"I know that a Dual Core is generally worse than a Core 2 Duo."**

Core 2 Duo is also a dual core processor. Dual Core is not the name of any model or range of products; it's a technology. What you probably mean to say is that Pentium D is worse than Core 2 Duo.

Comment: @Om Nom Nom - I could be wrong on this, but I have seen loads of computers for sale that have "Dual Core" as the processor type.  Here are two examples: http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16883117045 and http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16834146705

Comment: @vaccano Those are "Pentium Dual Core". Dual core (without Pentium) is a general term.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Core i3 is the successor to Intel Core 2 - series. It has an integrated GPU (Graphics Processing Unit) and can be seen as the lesser version of the Intel Core i7 and Core i5 series. And yes, it has two cores.

UPDATE:
Also from [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Core_i3#Nehalem_microarchitecture_based):

> With the Nehalem
>   microarchitecture[14], Intel
>   introduced a new naming scheme for its
>   Core processors. There are three
>   variants, Core i3, Core i5, and Core
>   i7, but the names no longer correspond
>   to specific technical features like
>   the number of cores. Instead, the
>   brand is now divided from low-level
>   (i3), through mid-range (i5) to
>   high-end (i7)[15]. Common features of
>   all Nehalem based processors include
>   an integrated DDR3 memory controller
>   as well as QuickPath Interconnect or
>   PCI Express and Direct Media Interface
>   on the processor replacing the aging
>   quad-pumped Front Side Bus used in all
>   earlier Core processors. Also, all
>   these processors have 256 KB L2 cache
>   per core, plus up to 12 MB shared
>   level 3 cache. Because of the new I/O
>   interconnect, chipsets and mainboards
>   from previous generations can no
>   longer be used with Nehalem based
>   processors.

Comment: Rank from Worst to Best for Intel processors (generally):

Intel Core Series < Core 2 < Core i3 < Core i5 < Core i7 < Core i9

Comment: Also, processors with 2 cores on it have Duo in the CPU name, processors with 4 core are labeled Quad, etc

Comment: Not necesarily... The I-series don't have DUO in the name but do have 2 cores.

Comment: The i3 typically has 2 cores, the i5 has either 2 cores with hyperthreading or 4 full cores (depending on model), and the i7 is 4 cores.  i9 will be the "extreme" edition...

Comment: They removed the Solo/Duo/Quad from the new family line names.  It's just i3, i5 and i7.  The number of cores depends on the model (Core i3-530, Core i3-540 etc.)